# I have 3 buttons with a JavaScript function each and only one of them working

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, visibility

I've been trying to make a Chrome expansion. I have 3 divs and I need them to show only when a button is clicked (each div responds to a button). Also I need the 2 divs left to hide (only one div showing simultaneously).

This is the code I have so far:

JavaScript (is a Chrome extension so JavaScript has to be in a separate file):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#hsp').addEventListener('click', myFunctionHSP);
  document.querySelector('#latam').addEventListener('click', myFunctionLATAM);
  document.querySelector('#mlb').addEventListener('click', myFunctionMLB);
});

function myFunctionHSP() {
  var hsp = document.getElementById("toggleHSP");
  var latam = document.getElementById("toggleLATAM");
  var mlb = document.getElementById("toggleMLB");

  if (hsp.style.display === "none") {
    hsp.style.display = "block";
    latam.style.display = "none";
    mlb.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunctionLATAM() {
  var hsp = document.getElementById("toggleHSP");
  var latam = document.getElementById("toggleLATAM");
  var mlb = document.getElementById("toggleMLB");

  if (latam.style.display === "none") {
    latam.style.display = "block";
    hsp.style.display = "none";
    mlb.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunctionMLB() {
  var hsp = document.getElementById("toggleHSP");
  var latam = document.getElementById("toggleLATAM");
  var mlb = document.getElementById("toggleMLB");

  if (mlb.style.display === "none") {
    mlb.style.display = "block";
    latam.style.display = "none";
    hsp.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggleHSP {
  widht: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: red;
  display: none;
}

#toggleLATAM {
  widht: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: red;
  display: none;
}

#toggleMLB {
  widht: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.division {
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.division:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"> <button class="division" id="hsp" onclick="myFunction()"> HSP </button> <button active class="division" id="latam"> LATAM </button> <button class="division" id="mlb"> MLB </button></div>
  <div id="toggleHSP">
    TEST HSP
  </div>
  <div id="toggleLATAM">
    TEST LATAM
  </div>
  <div id="toggleMLB">
    TEST MLB
  </div>
  <div> Test info bar </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be glad if I can have any help.

Comment: `=` -> assignment, `==` or `===` -> comparison

Comment: Where's this element in your HTML `document.querySelector('#latam')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minor errors:

1) Your `#hsp` div was setting `onclick=myfunction()` which doesn't exist and was causing an error.

2) You had one of your querySelectors for the `#cross` button wrong, it was looking for `#latam` which doesn't exist

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#hsp').addEventListener('click', myFunctionHSP);
  document.querySelector('#cross').addEventListener('click', myFunctionLATAM);
  document.querySelector('#mlb').addEventListener('click', myFunctionMLB);
});


function myFunctionHSP() {
  var hsp = document.getElementById("toggleHSP");
  var latam = document.getElementById("toggleLATAM");
  var mlb = document.getElementById("toggleMLB");
  if (hsp.style.display !== "block") {
    hsp.style.display = "block";
    latam.style.display = "none";
    mlb.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunctionLATAM() {
  var hsp = document.getElementById("toggleHSP");
  var latam = document.getElementById("toggleLATAM");
  var mlb = document.getElementById("toggleMLB");

  if (latam.style.display !== "block") {
    latam.style.display = "block";
    hsp.style.display = "none";
    mlb.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunctionMLB() {
  var hsp = document.getElementById("toggleHSP");
  var latam = document.getElementById("toggleLATAM");
  var mlb = document.getElementById("toggleMLB");

  if (mlb.style.display !== "block") {
    mlb.style.display = "block";
    latam.style.display = "none";
    hsp.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#toggleHSP {
  widht: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: red;
  display: none;
}

#toggleLATAM {
  widht: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: red;
  display: none;
}

#toggleMLB {
  widht: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.division {
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 0px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.division:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header"> <button class="division" id="hsp"> HSP </button>
    <button active class="division" id="cross"> LATAM </button>
    <button class="division" id="mlb"> MLB </button></div>

  <div id="toggleHSP">
    TEST HSP
  </div>

  <div id="toggleLATAM">
    TEST LATAM
  </div>

  <div id="toggleMLB">
    TEST MLB
  </div>

  <div> Test info bar </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `=` -> assignment, `==` or `===` -> comparison